# ng-options not producing dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am making a dropdown select to select venues in the add_event.html.

```
<select ng.model="venue" ng-click="getVenues()" ng-options="venue.name for venue in venues"  class="form-control"> 
</select>
```

The getVenues() is in the events controller which the add_event.html uses:

```
$scope.getVenues = function(){
  $http.get('/api/venues').then(function(response){
    $scope.venues = response.data;
  });
}
```

But for some reason the dropdown doesn't get populated?

The /api/venues does indeed produce an array of venues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be **`ng-model`** and use **`ng-init`** instead of **`ng-click`**

```
<select ng-model="venue" ng-init="getVenues()" ng-options="venue.name for venue in venues" class="form-control"> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks fro the help! The dropdown box is now produced but isn't at all populated? Might you know why?

Comment: you are missing " in ng-repeat, check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="selectedVenue" ng-init="getVenues()" ng-options="venue.name for venue in venues track by venue.id" class="form-control"> 
</select>
```

This will allows you prepopulate data on load. keep the selectedVenue (the value to be prepopulate)

Comment: thanks. Given that i am adding  the venue to the event, do you know how I can get back the venues properties (like name, date, etc...) For instance to get the event name you do {{event.name}}- how can i do like {{event.venue.name}}? Thanks